# Adding to a ObservableCollection<string>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**Edit: Changed List to ObservableCollection, got the same issu**e

I have got a global object which holds values needed for the duration of the application runtime. For some reason the ListView isn't being populated, not too sure if I have coded something wrong, or if the ListView simply isn't being updated for some reason.

Here is the class:

**App.xaml.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Global values for use during application runtime
/// </summary>
public class runtimeObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

    }
    private ObservableCollection<string> _hashList;
    public ObservableCollection<string> hashList
    {
        get { return _hashList; }
        set
        {
            if (value = "true")
            {
                _hashList.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                _hashList.Add(value);
                OnPropertyChanged("hashList");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have created a command to populate this List so I can test it's binding. Here is the command:

**Commands.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Command: Test
/// </summary>
public static RoutedUICommand Test
{
    get { return _Test; }
} 
public static void Test_Executed(object sender,
            ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var runtime = (runtimeObject)Application.Current.TryFindResource("runtimeVariables");
    runtime.hashList = "ONE";
    runtime.hashList = "ONE";
    runtime.hashList = "ONE";
    runtime.hashList = "ONE";
    runtime.hashList = "ONE";
}
public static void Test_CanExecute(object sender,
                    CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;
}
```

Here is my ListView with the binding, the way I have binded it works for a text box on another property, I have defined the static resource like this `<local:runtimeObject x:Key="runtimeVariables" />` within `App.xaml`
**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<ListView Height="150" Width="400" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource runtimeVariables},Path=hashList}"/>
```

**Edit:**

> why this?
>
> ```
>   runtime.hashList = new ObservableCollection<string> { "one" }; shouldn't it be:
>
>  runtime.hashList.Add("one"); ?
> ```

That's what I though, however if I change
`runtime.hashList = new ObservableCollection<string> { "five" };`
to this
`runtime.hashList.Add("one");`

How then do I handle that in the class property?

```
else
{
    _hashList.Add(value);
    OnPropertyChanged("hashList");
}
```

I get this error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert
>   "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection" to
>   "string"

**Edit 2:**
I want to be able to send a string to my class property, so that I can simply either add a new value to my List, or clear it, but it needs to return the List when requested.

But I can't do this can I? As in order to return the `ObservableCollection<string>` I need to set it like so:

`public ObservableCollection<string> hashList { }`

but this doesn't allow me to send just string data, as it can't convert string to `System.Collections...`

If this makes sense.

Comment: Try using an `ObservableCollection` rather than `List`

Comment: Or you can rise notification event yourself after each change (not really the right way): `runtime.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(runtimeObject.hashList))` after adding items. And you should definitely look into [naming guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040(v=vs.110).aspx) before it's too late

Comment: `runtime.OnPropertyChanged("hashList")` if he's using an older version of C#

Comment: @NedStoyanov Updated my post, same issue still

Comment: you definitely have no binding errors in your output window?

Comment: Hmm actually I do get this error for some reason: `Field 'runtimeObject._hashList' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null`

Comment: Yeah, because you don't initialize `_hashList` when you declare it and your setter does not actually set `_hashList` it just adds and removes items from the private backing object (which does not exist).  I don't see how `Test_Executed` does not throw a bunch of runtime exceptions.

Comment: why `_hashList.Add(value);` in the class? Really, this code doesn't seem to make much sense, from the information you provided.

Comment: Just realized I messed up the command and it wasn't actually firing. Updating post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `INotifyPropertyChanged` in this case to have the `ListView` update itself.  That event is used when the entire object is replaced, i.e. you replace the collection with an entirely different collection.  What you are really interested in doing is updating the `ListView` when items are added to or removed from the collection.  That is handled with an entirely different event: `INotifyCollectionChanged`.  If you bind `ItemsSource` to a collection that implements that event then the `ListView` will automatically update itself when the collection changes.  `ObservableCollection` implements that event so that is the collection you want to use.

I would replace your `runtimeObject` with this:

```
public class runtimeObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

    }

    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _hashList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> hashList
    {
        get { return _hashList; }
    }
}
```

And then change your`Test-Executed` method to this:

```
public static void Test_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var runtime = (runtimeObject)Application.Current.TryFindResource("runtimeVariables");
    runtime.hashList.Add("one");
    runtime.hashList.Add("two");
    runtime.hashList.Add("three");
    runtime.hashList.Add("four");
    runtime.hashList.Add("five");
}
```

Comment: Damn, I have been going about this all wrong... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your are raising `PropertyChanged` for `hashList`, but the `hashList` instance has NOT changed, only the CONTENT of `hashList` has changed. WPF has optimisations built in that can prevent any updates occuring if the object hasn't actually changed.

If you want WPF to respond to changes to the content of the list, you need to fire `CollectionChanged` instead, and the simplest way to do that is to use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`.

Answer (score 1):

The ListView has no idea that there were new values added to your list, because `List<T>` doesn't implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
You have following options:

- You can change the `List<T>` class to `ObservableCollection<T>` class.
- you can make your own list class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`
- you can after populating the list fire `OnPropertyChanged` on your object
- you can just fill the list with values before your ListView instantiates.

EDIT:

why this?

```
      runtime.hashList = new ObservableCollection<string> { "one" };
```

shouldn't it be:

```
     runtime.hashList.Add("one");
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
var runtime = (runtimeObject)Application.Current.TryFindResource("runtimeVariables");
runtime.hashList = new ObservableCollection<string> { "one" };
runtime.hashList = new ObservableCollection<string> { "two" };
runtime.hashList = new ObservableCollection<string> { "three" };
runtime.hashList = new ObservableCollection<string> { "four" };
runtime.hashList = new ObservableCollection<string> { "five" };
runtime.hashList = new ObservableCollection<string> { "six" };
```

Each time, you're creating a new list.  You want to assign the `ObservableCollection` to the `runtime.hashList` property once, then add each string to the collection:

```
var runtime = (runtimeObject)Application.Current.TryFindResource("runtimeVariables");
runtime.hashList.Add( "one" );
runtime.hashList.Add( "two" );
runtime.hashList.Add( "three" );
runtime.hashList.Add( "four" );
runtime.hashList.Add( "five" );
runtime.hashList.Add( "six" );
```

The `ObservableCollection` class implements another interface called `INotifyCollectionChanged` which follows a pattern similar to `INotifyPropertyChanged`, except that it raises an `OnCollectionChanged` event whenever the contents of the collection are changed.  WPF listens for changes to the collection on that event and updates the display appropriately.